# Debian often reboots halfway through resume from suspend to disk (hibernate)

Tags: linux, debian, hibernate, suspend

I'm on a Lenovo ThinkPad W510, using Debian Squeeze but with the Kernel and acpi-related packages from testing (this was [necessary to make hibernate work in the first place](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:W510)).

When I hibernate my laptop (suspend to disk) and try to wake (resume) it, about half of the time resume fails halfway through and the computer just reboots.

Here's my /var/log/pm-suspend.log after one such failed hibernate/resume cycle: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5358991/pm-suspend.log

I'm not savvy enough to make much sense of it on my own, maybe somebody can?

Comment: Actual excerpt of `/var/log/syslog` after such reboot would be helpful

Comment: Where on that page does it indicate that one should install the acpi packages from testing?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
When I installed the 2.6.38bpo kernel it wanted to change the /dev/sda2 I had
in /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume to ...
RESUME=UUID=<swap uuid> 
(no quotes)
```

```
In /etc/default/grub:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=<number of swap partition>"  
$ update-initramfs -u
```

From http://lists.debian.org/debian-backports/2011/09/threads.html#00047